# Why does my dataframe shows X rows but my DataFrame.tail ends ina number much smaller

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONHcZ.png)

My dfg.shape shows 8529019 rows × 14 columns but the last row of my dfg view is 631225.

Comment: Maybe the index of your dataframe is messed up. Try adding this line before your print the df: `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: There can be duplicate values in the index (and also not every number has too appear in an Index). Extract the index and check if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the index of your dataframe is messed up. Try adding this line before your print the df: `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`